# How to resize a UIView to a specific height and width including its subviews?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, resize, calayer

I'm having a problem on trying to properly resize a UIView.

sample scenario below:

```
// other view controller initializations

let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))
self.view.addSubview(containerView)
view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

let subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:containerView.bounds.size.width / 2, height: containerView.bounds.size.height))
containerView.addSubview(subView)
subView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

Let's say I'd like to resize containerView to a specific height and width, in such a way that the subview would also resize itself in parallel with the containerView.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can set `subView`s height and width anchors instead of specifying it in the constructors

Comment: What is your error? above code is working perfect. try with assign backgroundColor of both view for testing

Comment: best way is autolayout...

Comment: can you guys cite an example snippet or scenario of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I want by using a `UIStackView`.

```
let stackView = UIStackView(frame: .zero)
currentPage.addSubview(stackView)
constraintViewToSuperView(view: stackView) // my helper function to constraint stackview to bounds of parent

stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.alignment = .fill
stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
stackView.spacing = 1
stackView.backgroundColor = .red
```

The key is just to constraint the `UIStackview` into it's parent's bounds. Then any resizing I do with the parent would also proportionally resize the `UIStackview`'s children.

Answer (score 0):

Dont't forget to set the following property for the `subView`

```
subView.autoresizesSubviews = true;
```

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622559-autoresizingmask)

> An integer bit mask that determines how the receiver resizes itself
>   when its superview’s bounds change.

So using your example it would look something like this

```
let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, 
                                         y:0, 
                                         width: self.view.bounds.width, 
                                         height: self.view.bounds.height))

containerView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
self.view.addSubview(containerView)

let subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, 
                                   y:0, 
                                   width: containerView.bounds.size.width / 2, 
                                   height: containerView.bounds.size.height))

subView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
subView.autoresizesSubviews = true;
containerView.addSubview(subView)
```